# Python : Find Duplicate Items

Tags: python, duplicates

I have data in columns of csv .I have an array from two columns of it.Iam using a List of list . I have string list like this 
                [[A,Bcdef],[Z,Wexy]
**I want to identify duplicate entries i.e [A,Bcdef] and  [A,Bcdef]**

```
import csv
import StringIO
import os, sys
import hashlib
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import takewhile, count
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('person.csv','rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
listoflists = [];
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}

        a_list = [];
        for (c,n) in row.items():
            if c =="firstName":
                try:
                    a_list.append(n[0])
                except IndexError:
                    pass    
        for (c,n) in row.items():
            if c=="lastName":
                try:
                    a_list.append(n);
                except IndexError:
                    pass
        #print list(a_list); 
        listoflists.append(a_list);
        #i += 1      
    print len(listoflists);
```

I have tried a couple of solutions proposed here

- Using **set** (listoflist) always returns :unhashable type: 'list'
- Functions :  returns : 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

For example:

```
results = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, dict1.values()))
if len(results) > 0:
        print('Duplicates Found:')
        print('The following files are identical.  the content is   identical')
        print('___________________')
        for result in results:
            for subresult in result:
                print('\t\t%s' % subresult)
            print('___________________')
    else:
        print('No duplicate files found.')
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Do you need to identify duplicates (iow, do something with it) or just get rid of them?

Comment: I need to identify them for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a set of the string representations of you lists, which are quite hashable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than lists, you can use tuples which are hashable.

Comment: That's a much better suggestion than either of mine!

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [ ['A', "BCE"], ["B", "CEF"], ['A', 'BCE'] ]
res = []
dups = []
s = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]+x[1])
previous = None
while s:
    i = s.pop()
    if i == previous:
        dups.append(i)
    else:
        res.append(i)
    previous = i

print res
print dups
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to get rid of duplicates and don't care about the order, you could turn your lists into strings, throw them into a set, and then turn them back into a list of lists.

```
foostrings = [x[0] + x[1] for x in listoflists]
listoflists = [[x[0], x[1:]] for x in set(foostrings)]
```

Another option, if you're going to be dealing with a bunch of tabular data, is to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(listoflists)
deduped_df = df.drop_duplicates()
```